# Python Datetime with sequential issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-datetime

I am trying to write a script, where 3 variable of the list.

at first, see my current script:

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

x = ['jhon doe', 'GX']

y = ['donald ted', 'GY']

Z = ['smith joe', 'GZ']

start_date = dt.datetime(2019, 4,12)
end_date = dt.datetime(2019, 4,21)
daterange = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date)

for date in daterange:
    print(date)
```

I am troubled with this to bring output like this:

```
12/04/2019, jhone doe, GX
13/04/2019, donald ted, GY
14/04/2019, smith jhoe, GZ
15/04/2019, jhone doe, GX
16/04/2019, donald ted, GY
17/04/2019, smith jhoe, GZ
18/04/2019, jhone doe, GX
19/04/2019, donald ted, GY
14/04/2019, smith jhoe, GZ
21/04/2019, jhone doe, GX
```

It is clear if you see my expected output.

Can anyone tell me how to make this? the 3 variables is given above.

I think no need to write much about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would print it by a cycle (x, y, Z) using modulo function.

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

x = ['jhon doe', 'GX']

y = ['donald ted', 'GY']

Z = ['smith joe', 'GZ']

start_date = dt.datetime(2019, 4,12)
end_date = dt.datetime(2019, 4,21)
daterange = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date)

i=0
for date in daterange:
    if i % 3 == 0:
        print (date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'), *x, sep=',')
    elif i % 3 == 1:
        print (date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'), *y, sep=',')
    else:
        print (date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'), *Z, sep=',')
    i+=1
```

Result:

```
12/04/2019,jhon doe,GX
13/04/2019,donald ted,GY
14/04/2019,smith joe,GZ
15/04/2019,jhon doe,GX
16/04/2019,donald ted,GY
17/04/2019,smith joe,GZ
18/04/2019,jhon doe,GX
19/04/2019,donald ted,GY
20/04/2019,smith joe,GZ
21/04/2019,jhon doe,GX
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are missing a tool in your toolbox: `from itertools import cycle`.

A `cycle` allows you to create an iterator than can continuously go through a list. If you hit the end of the list it will go back to the beginning.

```
from itertools import cycle

import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

x = ['jhon doe', 'GX']

y = ['donald ted', 'GY']

z = ['smith joe', 'GZ']
r = (x, y, z)
pool = cycle(r)

start_date = dt.datetime(2019, 4,12)
end_date = dt.datetime(2019, 4,21)
daterange = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date)

for date in daterange:
    curent_person = next(pool)
    print('{}, {}, {}'.format(date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'), curent_person[0], curent_person[1]))
```

**Output:**

```
12/04/2019, jhon doe, GX
13/04/2019, donald ted, GY
14/04/2019, smith joe, GZ
15/04/2019, jhon doe, GX
16/04/2019, donald ted, GY
17/04/2019, smith joe, GZ
18/04/2019, jhon doe, GX
19/04/2019, donald ted, GY
20/04/2019, smith joe, GZ
21/04/2019, jhon doe, GX
```